# MySQL throws NULL value error on non-NULL update

Tags: mysql

The following query throws a `Column cannot be null` error, on trying to update the value to 0.

```
update schema.table set is_historical = 0 where id = 5;
[Code: 1048, SQL State: 23000]  Column 'is_historical' cannot be null
```

(The current value is 0, so effectively a no-op update attempted by a web-server)

The column definition is as follows:

```
`is_historical` tinyint NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
```

This query works fine most of the time. Intermittently it stops working and starts throwing this error. Creating a new connection doesn't help in that state. Rebooting the server I believe has fixed it in the past.

We used to be on MySQL 5.7 where we'd observed this a few times. Seeing the same thing on MySQL 8.x.

Any idea what might be going on?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the SQL mode to disable strict mode

```
SET SESSION sql_mode = 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
update schema.table set is_historical = 0 where id = 5;
```

If the update works, then you must set sql_mode in `my.cnf`

```
[mysqld]
sql_mode = ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

and run this to set the SQL mode for new incoming connections

```
SET GLOBAL sql_mode = 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
```

Comment: Thanks! I'd noticed that dropping STRICT_TRANS_TABLES from the sql_mode makes the error go away. Still thinking why 0 is invalid

Comment: For the definition of `is_historical` has `default ‘0’`, I would change it to `default 0` (get rid of the single quotes around the zero). I could see the zero as a string being auto converted to  number and then stored in `is_historical`. This hidden behavior might be a problem

Comment: I have trouble believing that the type conversion in `DEFAULT` is relevant to `UPDATE`.

Comment: In fact, if you try to make it `default 0`, and then `show create table`, you find it has been replaced with `default '0'`. Wacky!

Comment: @RickJames and BillKarwin Thank you, both